# 二次元配列の要素を取り出したい

Tags: python

```py
A = [['apple', 1],['banana', 2],['orange', 3],['grape', 4]]
```

リストAから要素を一つ取り出したいです。
以下のように試してみたのですが思うようにいきません。

```py
B  = [ x for x in A]
print(B)
>>>[['apple', 1], ['banana', 2], ['orange', 3], ['grape', 4]]
```

```py
B  = [ x[0] for x in A]
print(B)
>>>['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape']
```

期待する結果は下のようなものです。

```py
>>>['apple', 1]
```

実際のプログラムではこの処理の後にwhile文で['banana', 2]や['orange', 3]や['grape', 4]も
順に処理をしたいので、B = A[0]ではなくてfor文で取り出したいです。
変更すべき点を教えてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

内包表記とfor文がごっちゃになってませんか？

```
In [1]: A = [['apple', 1],['banana', 2],['orange', 3],['grape', 4]]

In [2]: for x in A:
   ...:     print(x)
   ...:
['apple', 1]
['banana', 2]
['orange', 3]
['grape', 4]
```